# Can the Overton Window be deliberately moved by espousing extremist views?

Tags: politics, sociology

The [Overton Window](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overton_window) is a political theory that 'describes a "window" in the range of public reactions to ideas in public discourse, in a spectrum of all possible options on a particular issue.'

When I have heard the Overton Window discussed it is usually in reference to a later concept:

> Other formulations of the process created after Overton's death add the concept of moving the window, such as deliberately promoting ideas even less acceptable than the previous "outer fringe" ideas, with the intention of making the current fringe ideas acceptable by comparison.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overton_window)

To summarise the idea in my own words: You can persuade people to move their opinion slightly and to accept ideas that are current unpalatable, by publicly proposing extreme, over-the-top views, until the more moderate versions seem like a reasonable compromise.

Wikipedia didn't cite any peer-reviewed articles.

**Is there any research to support or discredit the idea that publicly proposing unrealistically extreme views tends to move public opinion toward more moderate versions that are in the same political direction?**

*(I learnt while researching this question, that there is a novel by political commentator, Glenn Beck, by the same name. I haven't read this novel, and I am not attempting to address any of its contents.)*

**Update**: I see a few people repeating the claim in the comments, but still no-one has provided any evidence.

There is at least one competing model: that fringe elements on one side of a political spectrum will pollute the pool for others. That is, that people will dismiss moderate views because the extremists are so fringe. We could provide anecdotes for both of these theories, but that isn't evidence.

Comment: you didnt miss anything. The novel was mildly engaging and seemed to be building up but then seemed to just end which I have decided that overall I am greatful for.  But great question would love to read anything beyond the trype "referenced" by the book.

Comment: Sigh. I added the last sentence in an attempt to *avoid* the discussion falling into this political chasm. Not saying it is unimportant, but perhaps this isn't the forum.

Comment: @DVK I totally agree.  But the book... well it was not christmas sweater.  If Ronaldas Magnus had written it, it would not change the fact that it still sucked.

Comment: @Odd: rule #1 on SE: if you put "I'm not addressing X" in the question, answer and comments will discuss **only** X ;-)

Comment: I have no evidence of this, but I've "felt" that it's true for some time.  Not just politically either.  Of particular note, it's amazing how much more tolerant of vegetarians I became after dealing with the nutritional foibles of vegans.

Comment: @John - as an experiment, consider the idea of eating `hákarl`. Then look at whether you are OK with people eating live bugs :)

Comment: this is slightly offtopic, but the new novel, Rule 34, by Charles Stross uses the Overton Window in an interesting/fun/twisted way. Worth a read.

Comment: @DVK I'm familiar with both and must say I was okay with the bug eating before learning of the fermented shark.  The thing is, I don't think many people actually DO eat the fermented shark anymore.  It was sort of a "survive in hard times" food that became a "traditional, but who really wants any" food later.  It's "challenge food".  That said, I take and agree with, your point.  :-)

Comment: I think this question should be fixed to be answerable. The movability of the Overton window is intrinsic in the concept. However, this question is assuming that the Overton window is actually a proven fact and it's therefore begging its own answer. A more correct question is "is the Overton window a measurable effect?"

Comment: @Sklivvz, I am still pondering that. I fear we have a definition issue. To me the Overton Window is just the definition of a concept - a mental model to understand (static) public opinion. Whether it is measurable (i.e. repeatably, with meaningful units) doesn't seem relevant. The core question I am trying to get at is in bold, and (I notice now) doesn't actually mention the Overton Window.

Comment: In effect you are exactly doubting the Overton window exists.

Comment: I think the "Overton Window" exists in the same way "smelliness" exists - a concept that I can't measure, but I can use to communicate an idea. If we were to do *science* in the field, we'd want to define measurements far more precisely. I am doubting that the Overton Window can be deliberately moved via extremism. My reading - see first few paragraphs - is that Overton didn't claim anything about deliberately moving the window - just the idea of thinking about public opinion in that way. If you think the Overton Window implies it can be moved through extremism, we have a definition conflict.

Comment: I think it's just basic marketing. You provide a distorted view of the offer to drive the response. E.g. I always say that in Italy there is a centre-right party and a right party. The right party calls itself centre-right, and the centre-right party calls itself centre-left. So in practice people who want to vote centre-left are fooled to vote centre-right.

Comment: not enough for an answer, but this seems like an application of the [door in the face technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door-in-the-face_technique)

Comment: http://arxiv.org/ftp/cond-mat/papers/0410/0410199.pdf models something similar and reports no similar results in social psychology.

Answer (score 10):

It is a cognitive bias known as [anchoring bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring). In an extremely cited article (according to google it has over 20 thousand cites), cognitive scientists Tversky and Kahneman explain that:

> In many situations, people make estimates by starting from an initial value that  is adjusted to yield the final answer.
>   The initial value, or starting point, may
>   be suggested by the formulation of the
>   problem, or it may be the result of a
>   partial computation. In either case, 
>   adjustments are typically insufficient

and they furthermore propose the following example:

> In a demonstration of the anchoring effect, subjects were asked to estimate various quantities, stated in percentages (for example, the percentage of African countries in the United Nations). For each quantity,a number between 0 and 100 was determined by spinning a wheel of fortune in the subjects' presence. The subjects were instructed to indicate first whether that number was higher or lower than the value of the quantity, and then to estimate the value of the quantity by moving upward or downward from the given number. Different groups were given different numbers for each quantity, and these arbitrary numbers had a marked effect on estimates. For example, the median estimates of the percentage of African countries in the United Nations were 25 and 45 for groups that received 10 and 65, respectively, as starting points. Payoffs for accuracy did not reduce the anchoring effect.

—[Judgment under Uncertainty: Heuristics and Biases](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~nordhaus/homepage/documents/tversky_kahn_science.pdf) by Tversky, et al.
Science 27 September 1974: 1124-1131.
DOI:10.1126/science.185.4157.1124

It is *widely used* in marketing and advertisement.

For example it is forbidden by law to use this trick to advertise seasonal sales — for example, if a shop sells a pair of shoes for 50£ in January, it cannot expose a "<strike>70£</strike> 50£" sign to make it appear as a bargain in February.

Comment: Sklivvz, I believe the Overton Window idea has some overlap wiht the anchoring effect, but not much. If I recall correctly, the anchoring bias is strongest when there is not much other information to anchor your estimate on (i.e. the your participant number of 20000 would not inflate your estimate of the number of American states, which you're familiar with). I think there is literature on this where they espouse a Bayesian approach (your estimate would thus be the evidence = prior information and "evidence" (the biasing information), but I know next to nothing about it. Fun stuff!

Comment: @Ruben, I believe that the question: "Is there any research to support or discredit the idea that publicly proposing unrealistically extreme views tends to move public opinion toward more moderate versions that are in the same political direction?" is quite answered by anchoring alone...

Comment: I disagree. Anchoring may be part of the answer, but … well, see above. Opinions about contemporary issues aren't typically something where you have no other "anchor". I could also argue that it stretches belief to extend these findings which work best with numbers IIRC to value judgments.

Comment: Your last paragraph needs a reference. In particular, isn’t this simply forbidden because the crossed-out number implies a change which didn’t take place, i.e. is a lie?

Comment: @Konrad it's actually considered deceptive pricing practices to mark up a price just to mark down; in the US the FTC regulates this: http://www.ftc.gov/bcp/guides/decptprc.htm especially §233.1 paragraph (b) (which makes a good reference for Skliwz to borrow :) )

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield yet it is extremely common to do so. It's in fact the very premise on which sales season works, listing imaginary prices for products and then a "discounted" "sales price" (though frequently the products are specifically stocked for the "sale" and not part of the normal catalog of the store, so there is no "from" price at all, it's entirely made up).

Comment: @jwenting that's actually against the law in Europe. Cops visit shops and monitor these kinds of things.

Comment: @Sklivvz then why does it happen constantly? I've even seen shops advertising with "now discounted from 50 Euros to 69.99 Euros"....

Answer (score 5):

After viewing a debate about an issue, the distribution of audience opinions moves toward the middle of the two given sides.  To the extent that the Overton Window is influenced by televised debates and that "publicly proposing" ideas is similar to starting those ideas as a side of a debate, I see this as evidence for it being similarly manipulable.

(Sadly, even just to find my original sources, I see why you put this question here; the search terms "audience", "debate" and "opinion" are as muddy as they come.  The best I could do is http://www.overcomingbias.com/2009/04/why-refuse-to-debate.html  If anyone has better search-fu than I do in this domain, I would celebrate the inclusion of additional citations.)

Comment: Why is this downvoted? +1 from me.

Comment: And from me too!

Answer (score 3):

I read about a [new study that appeared in Frontiers in Psychology](http://www.frontiersin.org/Journal/DownloadFile.ashx?pdf=1&FileId=7946&articleId=52016&Version=1&ContentTypeId=21&FileName=fpsyg-04-00453.pdf) yesterday that is relevant to this question. It is open access, fairly readable and short, so I encourage you to check it out yourself.

The authors let German students construct a 9/11 narrative using a card deck with story elements. When they included more extreme statements, the number of official statements used dropped. This might be seen as evidence for shifting the Overton window by using extreme statements.
The authors also make the case that this mechanism may have been at work during the debate about Sarrazin's book "Deutschland schafft sich ab" (basically a German version of the Bell curve debate I talked about in my other answer).

The paper also has some general relevance for skeptics.SE because it's about how conspiracy theories form in people's minds.

#### Abstract

> Reptile prime ministers and flying Nazi saucers—extreme and sometimes off-wall conclusion are typical ingredients of conspiracy theories. While individual differences are a common research topic concerning conspiracy theories, the role of extreme statements in the process of acquiring and passing on conspiratorial stories has not been regarded in an experimental design so far. We identified six morphological components of conspiracy theories empirically. On the basis of these content categories a set of narrative elements for a 9/11 story was compiled. These elements varied systematically in terms of conspiratorial allegation, i.e., they contained official statements concerning the events of 9/11, statements alleging to a conspiracy limited in time and space as well as extreme statements indicating an all-encompassing cover-up. Using the method of narrative construction, 30 people were given a set of cards with these statements and asked to construct the course of events of 9/11 they deem most plausible. When extreme statements were present in the set, the resulting stories were more conspiratorial; the number of official statements included in the narrative dropped significantly, whereas the self-assessment of the story’s plausibility did not differ between conditions. This indicates that blatant statements in a pool of information foster the synthesis of conspiracy theories on an individual level. By relating these findings to one of Germany’s most successful (and controversial) non-fiction books, we refer to the real-world dangers of this effect.

#### Limitations

The study had a very small sample (30 in total). The study was vulnerable to expectancy effects from both researchers (scored card decks, knew condition) and students (they might have guessed the objective and helped along, manipulation was not subtle) and several outcomes were used, several of which could have been interpreted as supporting the hypothesis.

Thus, I wouldn't place too much trust in their findings until they're replicated in a much larger sample.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you'd like to read this, in a way it's a case study of what you're asking about. I think it counts a little more than an anecdote, because it's systematically done, but it's just one issue of course.

[Block (1995)](http://www.lscp.net/persons/ramus/fr/GDP1/papers/block95.pdf) describes how the publication of "The Bell Curve" by Herrnstein and Murray in 1994 shifted debate, so suddenly they were discussing "the degree of blacks' genetic inferiority" when it comes to IQ, when before it wouldn't have been okay to assert any genetic inferiority at all.

> What you consider as possible  affects what you think 
>   is an extremist position. The  critics  of Herrnstein and Murray have tended to 
>   trip  over  this  possibility. 
>   For example, in a New  York  Times  op.  ed.  critique that describes The Bell 
>   Curve  as  "bogus"  and  "nothing but  a  racial  epithet"  (Herbert,  1994),  Bob 
>   Herbert  insists  that  "the  overwhelming consensus  of  experts  in  the  field  is 
>   that  environmental  conditions  account  for  most  of  the  disparity  when  the 
>   test  results  of  large  groups  are  compared".  In  effect,  he  uses  known 
>   environmental effects on IQ to argue for a low degree of genetic inferiority  in 
>   blacks.

[...]

> Again, we can see that what you take as  possible  affects  what  you  take  as  actual.  As  with  the  passage  from Herrnstein  and  Murray  that  I  quoted  earlier,  agnosticism  ends  up  as agnosticism about  just  how  genetically inferior blacks  are.